# Database connectionstring based on input values - odbcDriverConnect

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown

Okay, so basically I embedded an Rmarkdown document in my Shiny application to provide the user with information about the steps he needs to fulfill to upload a dataset.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fBpC0.png)

My question is if it is possible to add a small widget, like this:

```
 actionButton(inputId = "help", icon = icon("question-circle"))
```

And when the user clicks on it there needs to come an overlay (a pop-up) with more detailled information and an example on how to do this. (so basically another Rmarkdown document)

I couldn't find any related examples on the forums / on the internet.
If someone could lead me in the right direction that would be awesome!

Comment: Have you checked out using `shiny::tags` `iframe`? See http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/tag-glossary.html

Comment: Might be a possible solution, thanks. I will look deeper into it.